# react-admin : prevent refresh for custom button in List

Tags: react-admin

I have a list with a custom button :

```
export const MyList = ({ ...props }) => {
    return <List exporter={false} perPage={50} {...props}>
        <Datagrid>
            <TextField source="name" />
            <TextField source="code" />
            <MyButton />
        </Datagrid>
    </List>
};

export const MyButton = ({ record }) => {
    const [state, setState] = useSafeSetState({
        error: false,
        loading: false,
        loaded: false,
    });

    const authProvider = useAuthProvider();

    const notify = useNotify();

    const redirect = useRedirect();

    const handle = async () => {
        setState({ error: false, loading: true, loaded: false })
        try {
            await authProvider.xxx(record.id);
            console.log('xxx successful');
            redirect('/anotherResource');
        } catch (e) {
            setState({ error: true, loading: false, loaded: false })
            notify(e.message, { type: 'error' });
        }

    };

    if (state.error) return <ErrorMessage message="ERROR"></ErrorMessage>;
    if (state.loading) return <p>...</p>;
    if (state.impersonated) return null;
    return (
        <Button onClick={handle}></Button>
    );
};
```

with this code, what happens at the network level :

1. http get for the list
2. http post for the authProvider.xxx
3. http get for the list
4. (and after) calls made by the other resource

what I'd like is to AVOID the 3rd call

my authProvider.xxx updates the token, and so it does the 3rd call with the new token which is not wanted

Questions :

1. why is there an "auto-reload" in the first place ?
2. how can i disable it ?

Comment: There is no "auto-reload" feature. If it reloads, it's because you changed the wuery parameters of the first list - or you did something else in a piece of code that you didn't include.